# Copy missing ID and price from one table to another

Tags: mysql

I have `table A` containing 1800 records and `table B` containing 800 records. I want to copy missing ID + price from `table A` to `table B`.

Both tables are with different columns. Common column is `ID`

I've started to build the query but what I can't figured out is how to tell which columns to copy only.

So far I have this

```
INSERT INTO productprice
SELECT products.productID, products.rrp FROM products
LEFT OUTER JOIN productprice ON productprice.productID = products.productID
WHERE productprice.productID IS NULL;
```

Problem also is second column values which I want to copy is column `rrp` from `table A` to column `price` in `table B`. Basically:

`products.productID` and `products.rrp` -> `productprice.productID` and `productprice.price`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query should work

```
INSERT INTO productprice (productID, price)
SELECT productID, rrp
FROM products
WHERE (productID, rrp) NOT IN 
   (SELECT productID, price
    FROM productprice);
```

Here is the demo: [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/27e55/1)

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
INSERT INTO productprice(id,rrp) SELECT products.productID, products.rrp FROM products LEFT OUTER JOIN productprice ON productprice.productID = products.productID WHERE productprice.productID IS NULL;
```

By specifying the columns in the insert statement. Now that wouldn't work if the table has some other required columns.